# What's the probability distribution of the minimum of dependent variables?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have $n$ variables defined by 
$$
Y_j = |X-c_j| \ \ \ \ (j=1,...,n)
$$
where $c_j$ are constants and $X$ is a gaussian variable (X ~ $N(\mu,\sigma^2$)).
What would be
$$
P(\min_j \ Y_j > 1) \ ?
$$
The minimum is on dependent variables, how could I get rid of it? Can I just work on the joint variable to isolate $X$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\min Y_j >1$ iff $|X-c_j| >1$ for each $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$. This is true iff $X> \max_j c_j +1$ or $X < \min_j c_j -1$. So the answer is $\Phi (\mu + \sigma (\min_j c_j -1))+1-\Phi (\mu + \sigma (\max_j c_j +1))$.

Comment: $\min Y_j >A_j$ does not make sense. You probably want $Y_j >A_j$ for all $j$, Yes,   this case is different.

Comment: Yes sorry, went to fast! Can I get rid of the absolute value the same way you did, turning the probability in two probabilities? I am not sure what I can or cannot do when working with joint variables...

Comment: So, is $P((Y_1,...,Y_n)>(A_1,...,A_n))$ equal to $P(X > max(c_j+A_j) + P(X < min(c_j-A_j))$ ?

Comment: No, the calculation is more complicated in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$$
P(\{\min_j Y_j > 1\}) = P(\{\text{all} \, Y_j > 1\})
$$

Now this is easy to calculate (just a product) in case $Y_j$ is independent. Else if dependent but Normal you need the covariance matrix and generally for this case the evaluation will be of a $N(O,I)$ random variable over a non simple region. To evaluate this for any covariance matrix $\Sigma$ you will need numerical analysis see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946719/finding-probability-in-multivariate-normal-distribution